# Getting facebook data via app -

Tags: php, facebook, oauth

I am attempting to get users facebook name etc via an app I am building. I am aware users will have to authorize this. I am looking at the facebook documentation but am having trouble getting to grips with exactly what I need to do.

I am loading my app as a canvas page. I have got the signed request such etc as in

if page is already liked do this:

if not show like our page option.

The page that is displayed after you have liked it has a question on which if you answer it will enter you into a competition. rather than having users fill out name and email I would like to enable oauth to get these details.

any ideas? thanks in advance

exisitng code:

if  ($like_status =="1")
{

```
if ( !empty ( $_REQUEST['enter_competition'] ) )
{
    $name = "";//needs to be amended to what we get from Facebook
    $email = "";//needs to be amended to what we get from Facebook
    if ($_REQUEST['answer']==$correctanswer)
    {
        $result = "Correct";
    }
    else
    {
        $result= "Incorrect";
    }

    $insert = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO competition ( name, email, answer ) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."', '".$result."')",$db);

    $displayforuser="true";
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the facebook API documentation at all? A good starting place is here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

didnt use ouath in the end. just collected manually. and I did read through the documentation as I stated in the original Q